# Aws glue spark "No such file or directory" but the file exist

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I want to execute a very simple spark script on Aws Glue as a spark job.
But I encounter the following error.

> An error occurred while calling o76.sql. No such file or directory 's3://bucketname/pathToFile/file.parquet

I'm sure that the file is present in the specified path but I don't get why it does not find the file.

Here the code:

```
spark_context = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().sparkContext
glue_context = GlueContext(spark_context)
spark = glue_context.spark_session


simple_query = f"""SELECT * FROM orion_staging.conforama_purchase LIMIT 10"""

email_purchase = spark.sql(simple_query)
url = 'my valid url'
result_df.write.format("parquet").option("header","true").mode("Overwrite").save(url)

print("DONE")
```

And the error :

> An error occurred while calling o76.sql. No such file or directory 's3://bucketname/pathToFile/file.parquet'

It happens when reading and the table I'm trying to read to is an Athena table.
I'm sure that glue is aware of this table because it display it when I'm browsing the glue interface.

I already tried to :
 - enable Hive support.

I would like also to try how to :
 - --enable-glue-datacatalog but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Can you check if the IAM role used for Glue job has proper access to the file in s3 bucket?

Comment: @Robert-reynolds did you figure it out?

Comment: @ShlomiSchwartz I called the support and they told me that Glue didn't reach it's full maturity yet. Not solution. From what I remember it was an inconsistent service.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to IAM role you have assigned to AWS GLUE Job make sure it has access to S3 bucket.